# $document -> addScript() not working on existing files

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to include JS and CSS files on a page in Joomla. For some reasons it's not working if a prepend the JURI::root() or something else.

Working:

```
$document->addScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js');
```

Not working:

```
$document->addScript(JURI::root() . '/media/media/js/clubliga/jquery.min.js');
$document->addScript('/jupgrade/media/media/js/clubliga/jquery.min.js');
```

Is `addScript()` somehow filtered? I've tried all combinations also with `.DS.` or `JHTML::script` ...

I'm at a loss ... Grateful for any hint!

EDIT: Joomla is running in a subdirectory: http://www.xyz.com/jupgrade

EDIT2: Not working: There's no output.

EDIT3: The problem seems to be the jupgrade (=JURI:root(true)) at the beginning of the path. For some reasons it's blocking the output. If I skip it at the beginning I get the link displayed but now with the wrong path.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not working", e.g. is the path incorrect or is the script tag not being output?

Comment: Have you tried `JURI::base()`? Assuming the paths you're specifying also reside within that subdirectory it should work fine. Are both working and broken examples in the same page? `addScript()` should not filter anything.

Comment: I've tried `JURI::base()` now but it's not working either. Both working and not working examples are in the same page. Tried with both at the same time -> not working either.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution: There are no links to local JS Files. Joomla is taking all local JS files and is packing them into a chached file. Therefore only JS files (like the google one) are not merged together.

Haven't realized that. *facepalm*

Thanks for spending your time & energy!

Comment: As much as I think caching via the Template Manager works well, it does have it's down sides, especially when it comes to development and thus I always turn off the caching. glad you got it sorted though ;)